# Remove Text after div jQuery

Tags: jquery, text

I've been looking for how to do this an i can't find a good answer or the proposed solution doesn't work? I would appreciate someone helping me out.

For example, if I have the following.

```
<div class="cons-info-question-container  field-required">

<div class="form-content"></div>
*
<div class="form-content"></div>
*
</div>
```

How can I remove the * after each .form-content?

I've added aftertext.js so I can add text but I thought this plugin also allowed for removing aftertext as well, via .afterText().remove()/.hide()? Maybe i'm way off base?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery does not have a convenient way to select text nodes. However, you can use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function to reduce the number of matched elements, and then use [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

For example, calling the following jQuery will remove the `*` elements from `.cons-info-question-container`:

```
$('.cons-info-question-container').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== '';
}).remove();
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8Lopwm8/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.cons-info-question-container .form-content').each(function () {
    var next = this.nextSibling;
    if (next && next.nodeType === 3) {
        $(next).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wasn't able to get this to work, but i'm still looking at it.

Comment: is jQuery on the page? If not I can tweak the answer to use plain/vanilla js

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all the `HTML` of `.cons-info-question-container` with the `HTML` of its children.

```
$(".cons-info-question-container").html($('.cons-info-question-container').children());
```